# Importing number fields which contain commas and random letters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with some random numbers and letters.
What I have done is removed all the random characters by using a function to do a `.replace` on the commas and letters.

Then I converted the dataset to string so I can run the function, because you can't run `.replace` on anything other than a string, i.e. I did `df = df.astype(str)`

So now I have data like:

```
|Column1: | Column2:| 
---------  ---------
|1000     | 56441.2 |    
|3552.6   | 1454.6  |
|5654.9625| 4       |
```

So when I run `df.dtypes()`, the dtypes for both columns are 'object'.
I would like to do some maths functions on these at a later stage, so would probably need to convert these to number format?

Could you please advise how to convert to number? I've tried:

- `pd.numeric` which converts the columns into a float64, however doesn't change the format
- `.map('{:,f}'.format)` and `.map('{:,d}'.format)` which don't seem to work

Comment: what do you mean by "*however doesn't change the format*"? There is no *format* with floats, just floats ;)

Comment: Right, yeah, figured that's the case xD